# How to make Ubuntu Budgie terminal open the already running terminal instead of opening new window

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-budgie

How do I make terminal shortcut in ubuntu budgie open the already running terminal instead of opening the new window?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make a launcher for your terminal open an existing terminal instead of opening an new instance, edit the `Exec=` line of the corresponding `.desktop` file. You will find the launcher for your terminal in `/usr/share/applications`.

To customize the launcher, copy it first to `~/.local/share/applications`. Then change the command on the `Exec=` line according to one of the following methods. That local copy of the launcher will replace the system wide one. The advantages of this approach over editing the system wide file are that 1) you do not need to be root to do the changes, and 2) changes will never be overwritten by a system update.

The approach given here is universal. It is not limited to your Budgie desktop environment, can work for any application and can also be used in shortcut keys.

*Option 1. `wmctrl`*

A very simple trick is to use the following command for your shortcut key:

```
sh -c "wmctrl -x -a gnome-terminal-server || gnome-terminal"
```

This will try to switch to a window with class "gnome-terminal". If that fails, it will launch the terminal. Of course, you need to substitute `gnome-terminal-server` and `gnome-terminal` by the actual WM_CLASS and command, respectively,  for your terminal application.

- You can find the correct window class for your application with the command `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`. After running the command, click the window about which you want to have the information, and you will see the WM_CLASS.
- `wmctrl` is not installed by default: you may need to install it first.

*Option 2: `jumpapp`*

A more "luxury" approach involves using a utility `jumpapp`, which actually relies on `wmctrl` for the "hard work". This tool exists on Github, and is not available within the standard Ubuntu software repositories. A [.deb file is available](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp/releases) for easy installation, though.

It allows for some more flexibility, avoiding the need for some scripting. For example, if more than one application window is open, repeatedly pressing your hotkey will cycle through the windows. See [an extended article on it here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/run-or-raise-application-windows-on.html).